# Object.getPrototypeOf(async function () { }).constructor vs eval vs vm.runInThisContext

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider:

```js
import vm from 'node:vm';
const obj = {x: 5};
const toRun = `Promise.resolve(obj)`;

var x = await (Object.getPrototypeOf(async function () { }).constructor("return " + toRun)());
var y = await vm.runInThisContext(toRun);
var z = await eval(toRun);
```

I'm familiar with why `eval` is evil, not recommended, etc. But I'm more-so interested in understanding the fundamental differences of the pros/cons of each of these types of scripts as they all "work" and produce the same result.

Things such as event-loop blocking, "microtaskMode" benefits, shared memory etc.

Comment: I can't comment about the different paths you've displayed here that do the same thing, but I can tell you that all of this involves running code that was unknown at compile / development time, and it's all dangerous. In HTML 5, there is a page header Content-Security-Policy, which shuts down all of this, including using inline element event handling and adding new script libraries. Bottom line: Any benefits of coding like this are dwarfed by the potential vulnerabilities.

Comment: "*they all "work" and produce the same result*" - I doubt that. `obj` is not a global variable.

Comment: Why are you using `AsyncFunction` instead of the normal `Function` constructor?